# $scope variable value not accessible outside of $http success callback in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am just started learning AngularJS.

I created a simple app to display content in json file. But however the the data assigned to scope inside the $http, returns undefined outside.

```
var app= angular.module('app',[]); 

app.controller('apCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

  $http.get('/path/to/data.json').success(function(){

   console.log(data); // returns data --working
   $scope.data=data; // assiged
   console.log($scope.data);  // returns data --working

  });

  console.log($scope.data); // returns 'undefined'  --not working

}]);
```

Please  help me to understand this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, `$http` service communicate with remote servers via `XMLHttpRequest` or `JSONP`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are making an asynchronous call. The data is not prepared when you try to call it from outside of success function. Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

For example, if you wait for a couple seconds, it'ld show:

```
app.controller('apCtrl',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope, $http, $timeout){

  $http.get('/path/to/data.json').success(function(){

   console.log(data); // returns data --working
   $scope.data=data; // assiged
   console.log($scope.data);  // returns data --working

  });
  $timeout(function(){
    console.log($scope.data);
  }, 2000);

}]);
```